# How to get values inside a chart without clicking

Tags: charts, ionic2, chart.js

I used   `import { Chart } from 'chart.js';` to show charts inside my app and used the following in ts file

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
console.log("milk total",this.chartValue);
        this.barChart = new Chart(this.barCanvas.nativeElement, {

                type: 'bar',
                data: {
                    labels: ["Milk", "News Paper", "Laundry", "Fruit/Veg"],
                    datasets: [{
                        label: '# of Total Price',
                        data: this.chartValue,
                        backgroundColor: [
                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
                        ],
                        borderColor: [
                            'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                        ],
                        borderWidth: 1
                    }]
                },
                options: {
                    scales: {
                        yAxes: [{
                            ticks: {
                                beginAtZero: true
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }

            });
}
```

[image]

I am able to get above mentioned array values 
But i am getting these values. 
[image]

I am able to get the array values like "22","0","18"..... only if i click on the red color label on top of my bar chart. i need the chart to show its value once the page gets loaded, and suggest me how to remove that red label

Comment: No not from api only within the app before the page gets active array gets filled @ɢʀᴜɴᴛ

Comment: @GRUNT post your answer again this.barchart.update it worked now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with your code. It should work as is.

Perhaps try force updating the chart after creating it, using the [**`update()`**](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html#updateconfig) method, as such :

```
ionViewDidLoad() {

   this.barChart = new Chart(this.barCanvas.nativeElement, {
     ...
     ...
   });

   this.barChart.update();
}
```